# Simple looking integral : How do I solve it?

Tags: calculus, integration

I came across this integral in one of my senior's old notebooks. It look like, 
$$
\int \frac{1}{x^{2}(x^{4}+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$
It looked pretty simple to look at, however when I tried solving it. I kept going in circles.

**I believe it in non-integrable. Am I right?**

**Is there any way to solve it?**

Regards.

Comment: It's an elliptic integral. You won't be able to do it with "elementary functions".

Comment: a solution by Maple looks like that $$-{\frac {\sqrt {{x}^{4}+1}}{x}}-1/2\,{\frac {{x}^{3}}{\sqrt {{x}^{4}+1
}}}+{\frac {3/2\,i\sqrt {1-i{x}^{2}}\sqrt {1+i{x}^{2}} \left( {\it 
EllipticF} \left( x \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2}+i/2\sqrt {2} \right) ,i
 \right) -{\it EllipticE} \left( x \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2}+i/2\sqrt {2}
 \right) ,i \right)  \right) }{ \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2}+i/2\sqrt {2}
 \right) \sqrt {{x}^{4}+1}}}
$$

Comment: Plz see [https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Differential_binomial to get what the first comment says.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How do you solve it then?

Comment: @PragyadityaDas You learn about elliptic integrals. They are quite fascinating!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sure! Can you suggest a book may be? :D

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I read about them a little. It looks like **Elliptic integrals** are defined for **Definite Integrals** only. Am I wrong?

Comment: There are "complete elliptic integrals" (definite integrals) and "incomplete elliptic integrals" (indefinite integrals). The incomplete elliptic integrals are in effect inverse functions to elliptic functions.